Difference between LSTM and MLP
My teacher said me that:

We compare the performance of LSTM and multilayer perceptron (MLP) with one hidden layer in terms of training process, prediction accuracy and learning ability.

Anybody explain me hidden layer with respect to training process, prediction accuracy and learning ability for both LSTM and MLP.

Your question is very vague and a complete comparison would take a lengthy answer. But will try to grasp the core comparsion.
MLP is a, static feedforward architecture and it doesn't use any recurrent gates(getting information from the previous inputs in neurons). LSTM is a special recurrent architecture(RNN) which flows the data from input to output and loops back within the network. It uses gates to control it such as input, output, and forget gates to enable the network to learn.
When it comes to training, MLP has few parameters and is less complex compared to LSTM, it strives to learn static patterns with non-linearity. In contrast, LSTMs are complex & intensive training with longer times with more parameters with gates compared to MLP, excels in time-dependent relationships and have high accuracy, and can handle log dependencies of data since it has recurrent and learns temporal dependencies.
As your question is about hidden layers, MLP uses backpropagation to optimize the linear functions and ultimately it tries to approximate the weights and biases in hidden layers. In contrast, LSTM has the same backpropagation training fashion and often overcomes traditional RNN problems like gradient vanishing problems using gap length. But it gating linear functions to approximate. So the math behind the network is quite complex.
You can find more clarity in getting the algebra part here.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory). To conclude, hidden layer dynamics is a lengthy concern, I just highlight the contrast to get yourself in.

Your answer looks like chatgpt generated.

Not really, as your question in a vague fashion, I tried to highlight the overall picture, anyhow, I reformed it with the math behind the computation. Just ping me if you any help with the math. I'm happy to help.

Yes, I need the math.
